# Does new versions of Intel® HD Graphics family support CUDA?

Tags: graphics, cuda, gpu, intel

I got my new Dell Laptop recently which I noticed has the Intel® HD Graphics family GPU; so I was wondering does the latest series of Intel® HD Graphics family support CUDA?

I would appreciate any tips!

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: No. CUDA is available only on NVIDIA devices.

Comment: go opencl if it is HD4000 series or iris pro

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no, you can not directly run CUDA app on CPU. However, you may be interested in [project gpuOcelot](https://code.google.com/p/gpuocelot/) which:

> is a modular dynamic compilation framework for heterogeneous system,
>   providing various backend targets for CUDA programs and analysis
>   modules for the PTX virtual instruction set. Ocelot currently allows
>   CUDA programs to be executed on NVIDIA GPUs, AMD GPUs, and x86-CPUs at
>   full speed without recompilation.